# How can you pass a function as a template parmater where the function return is same as the template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I am trying to figure out how I can make a template class that works like the following:

```
template<typename T, typename Fn>
class Point
{
public:
    T x;
    T y;

    void pt(const std::string& x_str, const std::string& y_str)
    {
          x = Fn(x_str);
          y = Fn(y_str);
    }
    .... more Point stuff ....
};

typedef Point<float, std::stof> FPoint;
typedef Point<int, std::stoi> IPoint;
.....
```

and then when I read a string - say "100.25,200.25", I could split on "," (which I actually have figured out how to do, and then say, set that point:

```
FPoint a;
a.pt("100.25","200.25")
```

so far I have tried defining directly as I have above, I have tried:

```
template<typename T, T (C*)(const std::string&)>
.....
```

and

```
template<typename T, T Fn(const std::string&)>
......
```

and then doing:
    typedef Point FloatPoint;

and I get various errors like  cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'float (__cdecl *)(const std::string &)'or 'std::stof' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'convert_func' depending on how I try to define the parameter.  Any hints - nothing I have googled has seemed to help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the second parameter be a function pointer:
template
class Point
{};

Note that neither std::stof or std::stoi would be valid arguments for that template (they both take additional arguments), but it would be fairly easy to create wrappers that rely on the default parameters (the template argument has to match types exactly, while the call does not):
typedef Point fPoint;

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use

```
typedef Point<float, std::stof> FPoint;
```

since `std::stof` is a pointer to a function, not a type.

You could try changing the template parameter to a non-type parameter, such as:

```
template<typename T, T(*Fn)(const std::string&)>
class Point { ... };
```

but that won't work since `std::stof` has an optional parameter of type `std::size_t*`. The type of `std::stof`, that takes a `std::string const&` as the first parameter is `float (*)(std::string const&, std::size_t*)`.

If you try to shoehorn `Point` to match that declaration,

```
template<typename T, T(*Fn)(const std::string&, std::size_t*)>
class Point { ... };
```

you won't be able to use:

```
typedef Point<int, std::stoi> IPoint;
```

since `std::stoi` has a third parameter, `int base`. The type of `std::stoi` is `int (*)(std::string const&, std::size_t*, int)`.

I think your best option is to create two wrapper functions in your namespace and use them instead of using `std::stof` and `std::stoi` directly as template parameters.

The following demonstrative program works in my setup.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template<typename T, T(*Fn)(const std::string&)>
class Point
{
public:
    T x;
    T y;

    void pt(const std::string& x_str, const std::string& y_str)
    {
       x = Fn(x_str);
       y = Fn(y_str);
    }
};

namespace MyApp
{
   float stof(std::string const& in)
   {
      return std::stof(in);
   }

   int stoi(std::string const& in)
   {
      return std::stoi(in);
   }
}

typedef Point<float, MyApp::stof> FPoint;
typedef Point<int, MyApp::stoi> IPoint;

int main()
{
   FPoint a;
   a.pt("100.25", "200.25");
   IPoint b;
   b.pt("100", "200");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out - std::stof is actually std::stof(const string&, size_t*).  I put that in the template parameter (T (C*)(const std::string&, size_t*) and now I get errors in paces where I use Point as not having enough parameters.  After I fix that up, if I am still wrong, I'll come back and remove this answer.

Comment: Yup - that was it....  apparently because it is templated, I have to use all the parmeters, even though std::stof is defined as std::stof(const std::string&, size_t* = 0)